# jfeinstein10 SlidingMenu And WebView Control

Tags: android, webview, slidingmenu, hybrid

I have a problem when `jfeinstein10` and `webview`(Base control into activity) when want to close menu webview show a (like shadow):

screen shots:

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a28HM.png]

Comment: Same issue : https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/261